# Cannot locate javac.exe using the PATH environment variable

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to setup PhoneGap and eclipse. After downloading Phone-Gap i opened the command prompt changed the directory to **bin folder** in **android folder** of **download Phone-Gap folder**. as shown in Command Prompt and then tried to create **demo-app** by create command As shown in Picture:[image: Step which i performed]

But the **Environment Variable** are already added:[image: environment variables]

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yeah to some extent. I installed Visual Studio Hybrid App development it corrected all the paths This is my current  setting for PATH: **C:\Users\affan\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin**. After doing that what you told it gives error that **ant** not found and finally this worked.

Comment: Oh alright good thing. Well please accept my answer if you feel it answers the question. I couldn't predict the **ant** not being found, but I feel that I answered the question still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't ask a question so I'm not quite sure if you're expecting it to work with what you already have or if you're looking for help because you don't know what to do. Hopefully this helps:

Currently your `PATH` Environmental variable doesn't point to the location of the `javac.exe` file (it's in your Java `bin` folder).

Look at your `JAVA_HOME` System variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.7.0_51
```

That location is to the home directory of the Java files, so that's nearly to the `bin` folder which contains `javac.exe`. Just copy that path over to your `PATH` Environmental variable and slightly modify it to this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.7.0_51\bin
```

So just append that location to your `PATH` variable, which can point to multiple locations. Separate locations with a semi-colon. So your final `PATH` variable (the one at the very top of that window that you showed in a picture) would look like this:

```
C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.7.0_51\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of `javac.exe` should be something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` . So you should also add this location as an environment variable.